# I am using \input to inport a section title from another file, but even using \protect I get charters like <<30>>

Tags: section-titles

I have a directory devoted to document titles, one title per file.  Another directory is devoted to document abstracts, one abstract per file.

I am trying to create a catalogue of documents, in which each title is a division (\subsection or \subsubsection) and each abstract is the body for the division.

But even using \protect, the title line begins with the characters <<30>> .

Comment: `\protect` problems would cause strange errors when you compile.  `<<30>>` sounds maybe like a character encoding issue.  But you've not given us much to go with.  Can you trim it down to one `\input` file that's causing the problem, and post the 10 or so lines of code that make up a MWE?

Comment: I  constructed a MWE and the problem was not present.  However, in constructing the MWE, I simplified the directory structure.  Now I can go back and add the complexity and see where things go awry.  Thanks for suggesting the MWE.